# Add a folder from outside the repository to repo?

Tags: wordpress, git

I'm working on a WordPress theme, and I've just created a repository from the theme folder inside /wp-content/themes/ directory. But now I've moved some code from the functions.php file to two plugins in the /wp-content/plugins/ directory.

Question, can I add the plugins folder to my exiting repository?

Comment: You can store them directly in your repo and create `symlinks` to them in `/wp-content/plugins/`.

Comment: Thanks  Arkadiusz Drabczyk, it worked!

Comment: great, I converted into an answer. If you like it please mark it as accepted so that other users know that your problem has been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them directly in your repo and create `symlinks` to them in `/wp-content/plugins`. This is a popular method, many people use it to manage their `dotfiles` with `git`.